# PostGIS 2.1.1 compilation issue

Tags: postgis, raster2pgsql, compile

I tried to compile postgis-2.1.1 in RedHat 6.3 with:

```
# ./configure --with-pgconfig=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_config --with-gdalconfig=/usr/local/bin/gdal-config --with-geosconfig=/usr/local/bin/geos-config --with-xml2config=/usr/bin/xml2-config --with-gui  --with-raster --with-topology
```

It gives:

```
  PostGIS is now configured for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

 -------------- Compiler Info -------------
  C compiler:           gcc -g -O2
  C++ compiler:         g++ -g -O2
  SQL preprocessor:     /usr/bin/cpp -w -traditional-cpp -P

 -------------- Dependencies --------------
  GEOS config:          /usr/local/bin/geos-config
  GEOS version:         3.4.2
  GDAL config:          /usr/local/bin/gdal-config
  GDAL version:         1.10.1
  PostgreSQL config:    /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_config
  PostgreSQL version:   PostgreSQL 9.3.1
  PROJ4 version:        48
  Libxml2 config:       /usr/bin/xml2-config
  Libxml2 version:      2.6.26
  JSON-C support:       yes
  PostGIS debug level:  0
  Perl:                 /usr/bin/perl

 --------------- Extensions ---------------
  PostGIS Raster:       enabled
  PostGIS Topology:     enabled
  SFCGAL support:       disabled

 -------- Documentation Generation --------
  xsltproc:             /usr/bin/xsltproc
  xsl style sheets:
  dblatex:
  convert:              /usr/bin/convert
  mathml2.dtd:          http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/mathml2.dtd
```

But, when I compile I get:

```
# make
[...]
usr/local/lib/libgdal.so -L/usr/local/pgsql/lib -L/usr/kerberos/lib64 -ljpeg -lpng -lpq -lpthread -lrt -lcurl -ldl -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err -lidn -lssl -lcrypto -lxml2 -lz /usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.so /usr/local/lib/libgeos.so -lc -lm
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `isfinite'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [raster2pgsql] Error 1
make[2]: se sale del directorio `/root/Descargas/postgis-2.1.1/raster/loader'
make[1]: *** [rtloader] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio `/root/Descargas/postgis-2.1.1/raster'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried http://lists.osgeo.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/postgis-users you may get better help there. I think it's a little off-topic here.

Comment: It worked!
Althoug I'm working in RHEL 6.3, the workaround described in [http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2542](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2542) has worked.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

This isssue should be fixed in 2.1.2 branch here -- http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2542

2.1.2 has not been released yet though but you can pull 2.1.2 or just cut in the fix.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it doesn't work. I'm compiling in RedHat 6.3. I've tried to apply this workaround but it hasn't worked.